# Angular-Formly: Make a field required if option selected from dropdown box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

I want to make an input field required if an option has been selected from a corresponding dropdown box. My 2 fields are duplicated once an option is selected from a dropdown box so user is not limited to a single option. So... if `exportSupplier` is chosen then `agreementReference` becomes `required`. However if there's more than one `exportSupplier`and at least one of them is not chosen then the form treats `agreementReference` fields as `not required`.

How can I make a corresponding `agreementReference` field `required` if a corresponding `exportSupplier` has been chosen?

```
    vm.exportSuppliers = [{ exportSupplier: '', agreementReference: '' }];

    vm.exportSupplierFields = [
        {
            fieldGroup: [
                {
                    className: 'col-xs-6',
                    key: 'exportSupplier',
                    type: 'select2',
                    templateOptions: {
                        label: 'Export Supplier',
                        required: false,
                        options: [],
                        onChange: function() {
                            vm.addExportSupplier();
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    className: 'col-xs-5',
                    key: 'agreementReference',
                    type: 'input',
                    templateOptions: {
                        label: 'Agreement Reference',
                        onChange: function() {
                            vm.addExportSupplier();
                        }
                    },
                    expressionProperties: {
                        'templateOptions.required': '!!model["exportSupplier"]'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

    vm.addExportSupplier = function() {
        if (vm.exportSuppliers[vm.exportSuppliers.length - 1].exportSupplier || vm.exportSuppliers[vm.exportSuppliers.length - 1].agreementReference) {
            vm.exportSuppliers.push({ exportSupplier: '', agreementReference: '' });
        }
    };
```

my HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="supplier in vm.exportSuppliers" class="row">
    <formly-form model="supplier" fields="vm.exportSupplierFields"
        form="vm.informationExportSupplier.form" index="$index">
    </formly-form>
</div>
```

I have tried different variations to add $index into that 'templateOptions.required' field but without success.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried different variations to add $index into that 'templateOptions.required' field but without success.

```
<div ng-repeat="supplier in vm.exportSuppliers" ng-init="outsideIndex = $index">
    <formly-form model="supplier" fields="vm.exportSupplierFields"
        form="vm.informationExportSupplier.form"  ̶i̶n̶d̶e̶x̶"̶$̶i̶n̶d̶e̶x̶"̶
        options="{data: {outsideIndex: outsideIndex}}">
    </formly-form>
</div>
```

From the Docs:

> ### `options`
>
> Options for the form.
>
> #### `data`
>
> This is an object. Put whatever you want here.
>
> [— Angular-formly formly-form Directive API Refeerence](http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/formly-form)

Comment: I'm not sure how I could use this to set required value to a corresponding field in the expressionProperties.